# XML saving error in eclipse Indigo

Tags: xml, eclipse

Can anybody please let me know Why it pops up save failed and NullPointer error dialogue always while saving XML file in eclipse(Indigo). ??
Thanks.!!

Comment: just my 2 cents , check where are you saving the file , may be you can not save it on C:

Comment: @Satya, Actually i noticed that it's popping up the error while saving any xml file in eclipse. I don't understand what's wrong happened to the eclipse. Is there anything got corrupted in eclipse ??

Comment: if you are saying that you can not create a xml file in eclipse then this could be a problem with eclipse, however, if you can not create a XML file using programming in eclipse , then this is a problem with your file permissions.

Comment: Without a stack trace, all I can suggest is move up to the current supported release, Juno SR2, and see if it's still happening.